# How to deploy SparkJava REST API app to Google App Engine via Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spark-java

I have built a REST API for my project using SparkJava, and now I want to deploy it to Google App Engine. But after installing Google App Engine plugin in Eclipse i have got no clue how to do it. I have copied the src files from my previous project to a new Web Application Project and renamed the main() as init() as stated here http://www.sparkjava.com/readme.html#title18 and I have also updated the web.xml as stated. But the project doesn't run. Please guide!

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out?

Comment: not really! I do not even use SparkJava now :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy a spark Java web app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783646/how-to-deploy-a-spark-java-web-app)